# Older version Commands of opencv are not working in newer versions

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently using OpenCV 3.0.0 beta, and it fails to recognize `cv::FOURCC`, `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` and `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT` from older 
    versions. How would I go about using them in the newest version. Here's some sample code providing an example of where I might need them, and am unable to use them in OpenCV 3.0.0 beta.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
VideoCapture cap("H:\\images\\v1.mp4");
cv::VideoWriter writer;
string filename = "H:\output_video.avi";
int fcc = cv::FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3'); // Error Shown for this line
int fps = 20;
cv::Size frameSize(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), 
cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)); // Error Shown for this line
writer = VideoWriter(filename, fcc, fps, frameSize);

for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    writer.write(frame);
    namedWindow("Output Video");
    imshow("Output Video", frame);
    char key = (char)waitKey(50);
    if(key == 'q' || key == 'Q' || key == 27)
    {
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#afec93f94dc6c0b3e28f4dd153bc5a7f0

Comment: Thank you, berak... for the link. But how tp

Comment: Thank You.. berak for the link... But I am not getting how to use VideoWriter?? That four arguments are OK, but I can't declare that directly in the main function, which is giving error.

Comment: "But how tp " - you mean ? you'll have to erplace the constants with their newer version, etc. use the docs / tutorials / samples to find out. also: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html and https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp

Comment: replace cv::FOURCC with cv::VideoWriter::fourcc (it's a static function, that does not need an instance, only the scope

Comment: Thanks once again....